# How to push a release with Capistrano

Tags: git, capistrano, capistrano3

I am interested in using Capistrano to deploy my web app. The one concern I have is if I have multiple www nodes, I don't want each www node to hit our Git repo. Instead, I prefer if the machine that's responsible to deploying to all the www nodes pulled from the Git repo and then pushed that copy out to each www machine.

Is there a way to configure Capistrano (version 3) to do this?

Comment: Because you're worried about server load, or you don't want to have network access between the repo and www nodes?

Comment: Prefer not having to add SSH keys for 100+ www nodes.

Comment: If you don't get a better answer, you could configure all of the nodes to use the same key.

Comment: You should include Capistrano somehow in your question title.